# Generating a link with parameters from a two select menus

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select menus acting like a chained select.

What I would like to accomplish is to generate a link where the params are the id and value of each select.

For example:

- select 1 has id = "first" and value = "1"
- select 2 has id = "second" and value = "20"

The returning link must be www.mywebsite.com/popup.php?first=1&second=20.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is your problem? Also, what have you tried? (You can't get the two values? You can get them, but don't know how to build the URL string? You can build the URL string but cannot generate the link? Etc.)

Comment: You need to provide a better explanation of what you want. The above is not clear

Comment: @Liam I find it very obvious what he wants to do: he has two select elements, the second dependent from the first, and wants to build a hyperlink element from the selected ids/values.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
   function createURL(){
       var select1 = document.querySelect('#id');
       var value1 = select1.options[selects.selectedIndex].value;
       return "link?"+value1;
    }
    var url = createURL();
```